# How can I record and save flash video's with an H264 codec

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, h.264, flash-media-server

Right now I am working on an AIR 3.2 application which lets you stream a video to a Flash Media Server and saves it on a hard drive.

This sequence works fine with the standard Sorenson codec but I want to use H.264 for my videos. I found lots example code and implemented it in my code, but when I record a video of myself I am unable to re-watch it afterwards.

I found how to implement a H.264 encoding in a [realeyes blog post here](http://www.realeyes.com/blog/2011/10/31/new-in-flash-player-11-encoding-live-video-to-h-264avc/). My [code is here](http://www.mediafire.com/?4arxodzi08ssion).

It saves the video as a `.f4v` file, but my browser (I've tried the latest versions of both Chrome and Firefox, with the latest Flash) and also VLC are unable to load the video. I also used a program called Movie Player which is able to open the file but can only show the first frame and the audio. Neither am I able to upload the video to YouTube because they do not support the file extension.

Here is an example video file it saved: [H264Test1.f4v](http://www.mediafire.com/?dq3d0a6sffulp18).

My question is: How do I stream and save the movie with a file extension that I am able to re-watch while using the H.264 codec?

Comment: Can you upload an example `.f4v` file that you've generated somewhere? Also the actual code you're using would probably help.

Comment: Here is a test file: http://www.mediafire.com/?dq3d0a6sffulp18 and here is the code: http://www.mediafire.com/?4arxodzi08ssion @derobert

Comment: ffmpeg gives me a *multiple edit list entries, a/v desync might occur, patch welcome* warning, but it plays. If you rename it to `.mp4`, I suspect YouTube will take it.

Comment: Ok, YouTube still doesn't take it. I see also that playing with it more, ffmpeg doesn't really like it either...

Answer (score 1):

This is because of how FMS records the mp4 content, quite a few players won't be able to play the videos.

Download the Adobe F4V Postprocessor at this URL: http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/tool_downloads/

This should convert the video so it will be playable in other players.

Edit: I just tested the tool with some videos, it will indeed solve the issue of recorded f4v videos not playing in other players

Answer (score 0):

Use ffmpeg to convert the f4v file to flv using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i file1.f4v -sameq file1.flv
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [enter link description here](http://rainbowcreatures.com/product_flashywrappers.php) from Pavel Langweil. He have a great Theora / Vorbis encoder that generates small ovg files that you can easily convert to mp4 using ffmpeg.